# Keeping the content of a text file while the file is reloading in a new run of the c++ program

Tags: c++

I have a c++ program. The final output of this program is a matrix and I write it in a text file. whenever that I run my program by different inputs, a new matrix is made and it is written in the text file. But the previous content of my text file are deleted after each new run, while I need all of matrices with together. Is there any way for my purpose?
My code is in the below.
example.txt is my text file and I'm writing a 2d matrix named relation in this text file. I want in the next run of my program still I could have previous matrices.

```
 ofstream myfile ("/home/PROJECT/My_Tasks/example.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
   for(int c1=0;c1 < size;c1++){
    for(int c2 =0; c2 < size; c2 ++)
    {
     myfile << relation[c1][c2] << " " ;}
     myfile << endl;
    }
    myfile.close();
  }
  else cout << "Unable to open file";
```

Suppose the matrix after the first run is:

```
2 3 4
1 9 8
```

this will written in the example.txt but when I run the program for the next time it is deleted and new matrix will be appeared.

in the second run, it is:

```
6 4 1
8 8 5
```

But I want a way for having both matrices with together in my example.txt file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is appending. Check the docs [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/)

`ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("example.text", ios::app);`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will check it.